# Find Weight for minimum Manhattan Distance

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces, median

Let's say, I have three points $(1, 4)$, $(4, 3)$ and $(5, 2)$. I need to find weight $w_1$ and $w_2$ so that the point $(1, 4)$ be the centroid of the points in `Manhattan Distance`. Actually, the point $(1, 4)$ must have the minimum total distance from others.

How can I weight those X and Y coordinates to minimalize the total distance toward point $(1, 4)$?

Comment: If $X=(4,3)$ and $Y=(5,2)$ are given, then I do not understand your question. Their Manhattan distances from $A=(1,4)$ are equal to $4$ and $6$. What do you mean with weighting? And which distance would you like to minimize, exactly?

Comment: @Avitus, Thanks for your comment. Total distance from (4, 3) and (5, 2) to (1, 4) is, as you said, 4+6. But the total distance from (1, 4) and (5, 2) to (4, 3) is 4+2. Therefore the point (4, 3) would be the centroid here. I need to give weight to X and Y coordinate such that the point (1, 4) would be the centroid instead.

Comment: So, if $S=\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$ (sorry for changing names to points!) is the set of the 3 given points, the centroid $\bar{X}\in S$ is the element s.t.  $\sum_{X_i\in S}d_{MH}(\bar{X},X_i)$ is minimized, where $d_{MH}$ is the Manhattan metric. Did I correctly understand? given the set $S=\{(1,4),(4,3),(5,2)\}$ then the centroid is $\bar{X}=(4,3)$. You would like to have $\bar{X}=(1,4)$, instead. To do so you would like to "rescale" the points $(4,3),(5,2)$. Is it ok?

Comment: @Avitus, Yes. Exactly.

Comment: I added an answer, with the above idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is asking for two parameters (called the wieghts) $\lambda$ and $q$ s.t. the set

$$\mathcal S_{\lambda,q}:=\{(1,4),(4\lambda,3\lambda), (5q,2q) \} $$

has centroid given by $(1,4)$. We need to satisfy the inequalities

$$d_{MH}((1,4),(4\lambda,3\lambda))+d_{MH}((1,4),(5q,2q))\leq d_{MH}((4\lambda,3\lambda),(1,4))+d_{MH}((4\lambda,3\lambda),(5q,2q)),$$
$$d_{MH}((1,4),(4\lambda,3\lambda))+d_{MH}((1,4),(5q,2q))\leq d_{MH}((5q,2,q),(1,4))
+d_{MH}((5q,2q),(4\lambda,3\lambda)),$$

where $d_{MH}(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the Manhattan distance. 
The above inequalities simplify to

$$d_{MH}((1,4),(5q,2q))\leq d_{MH}((4\lambda,3\lambda),(5q,2q)),$$
$$d_{MH}((1,4),(4\lambda,3\lambda))\leq 
d_{MH}((5q,2q),(4\lambda,3\lambda)),$$

which are equivalent to

$$|5q-1|+|4-2q|\leq|4\lambda-5q|+|3\lambda-2q|, $$
$$|1-4\lambda|+|4-3\lambda|\leq|5q-4\lambda|+|2q-3\lambda|.$$

One can study the locus of points $(\lambda,q)$ satisfying the above inequalities, or directly search for a solution. I found, for example,

$$(\lambda,q)=(\frac{1}{2},2). $$

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll examine your solution as soon as get behind my PC. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Rescale $x$-coordinates with $(2/9)$ and $y$-coordinates with $(8/5)$, giving:
$$
   \left(\frac{2}{9}\times 4,\frac{8}{5} \times 3 \right) = \left( \frac{8}{9} , \frac{24}{5} \right) \qquad ; \qquad \left(\frac{2}{9}\times 5,\frac{8}{5} \times 2 \right) = \left( \frac{10}{9} , \frac{16}{5} \right)
$$
Centroid = $(9/9,20/5)$ .

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Appreciate it.

Comment: Hmm, looking at the accepted answer, it seems I've somehow misunderstood the question ..